# How Truncate command works in netezza

Tags: truncate, netezza

Can someone explain how truncate works in netezza database and why it is fast in deleting all the records. 
Need to know the internal login of deleting all the records from tables.

Comment: has your questions been answered, or were you looking for something else?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior varies a bit by version, but by 7.2.0.4 and later TRUNCATE can run concurrently with other queries against the same table as well as while backups are running.

When the TRUNCATE occurs the system notes the TXID of the transaction in which the TRUNCATE is run.

Any query that started a transaction prior to that TXID sees the table as it was before the TRUNCATE was run.

Any query that references the table while in a transaction that started after the TRUNCATE's TXID has committed will see an empty table because it knows to remove all of the rows created by lower TXIDs from the scan list.

Consequently,TRUNCATE is very fast because it just has to mark each extent deleted. Once all outstanding transactions that were stated earlier than the TRUNCATE's TXID have commited, then the system will quietly release all of that storage back to to the pool.